# How do I construct and compile this C# Expression with Generic types & lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, expression

I am trying to create a custom serializer.  It needs to be performant.

The idea is to construct and cache some `Func<…>` for each type

In this simplified example, I *successfully* construct the `Func` for STRING types, but I'm stuck on how to construct it for ARRAY types.

It could be helpful to imagine that I can now serialize the `Meow` class, but that I would fail to serialize the `Ruff` class.

```
class Program
{
    class Meow
    {
        public string Rawr { get; set; } = "X";
    }
    class Ruff
    {
        public Meow[] Grr { get; set; } = new[] { new Meow(), new Meow() };
    }
    static class Serializer<T>
    {
        static int DoSomething(string value, Stream stream) => value.Length;
        static int DoSomethingElse(T[] values, Stream stream) => values.Length;

        public static Func<T, Stream, int> GetSerializer()
        {
            var firstProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].GetGetMethod();

            var typeParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var compiledGetter = Expression
                .Lambda(
                    Expression.Call(typeParam, firstProperty),
                    typeParam
                )
                .Compile();

            var returnType = firstProperty.ReturnType;

            if (returnType == typeof(string))
            {
                var getString = (Func<T, string>)compiledGetter;
                return (T item, Stream stream) => DoSomething(getString(item), stream);
            }
            if (returnType.IsArray)
            {
                // var getArray = (Func<T, returnType>)compiledGetter;

                var elementType = returnType.GetElementType();

                // return (T item, Stream stream) => 
                //    Serializer<elementType>.DoSomethingElse(getArray(item), stream))
            }
            return (T item, Stream stream) => 0;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
        Console.WriteLine(Serializer<Meow>.GetSerializer()(new Meow(), s));
        Console.WriteLine(Serializer<Ruff>.GetSerializer()(new Ruff(), s));
        Console.ReadKey();
        // Should print "1", "2"
        // Currently prints "1", "0"
    }
}
```

Serializing `Meow` is easy.  The function will take the `T` and `Stream`, extract `string` from `T`, and pass them into `DoSomething(string, Stream)` to return a bool.

But while serializing `Ruff`, it encounters a property with return type `Meow[]`.  To serialize it, it needs to take `T` and `Stream`, extract an array of an unknown element type from `T`, and pass them into `Serializer<Meow>.DoSomethingElse(Meow[], Stream)`

The commented-out lines show the gist of what I think needs to happen.  But how can I create a compiled `Expression` for it all and finally return a `Func<T, Stream, bool>`?

EDIT:  Test code is now included.  When implemented, the `Ruff` serializer should spit out `2`, the length of the array.

EDIT #2:  **SOLUTION!** thanks to **Jeff Mercado**

Below is the working code (Just the GetSerializer method)

```
        public static Func<T, Stream, int> GetSerializer()
        {
            var itemTypeExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var streamTypeExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Stream));

            var firstProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().First();
            var propType = firstProperty.PropertyType;

            var getterExpression = Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.Property(itemTypeExpression, firstProperty),
                itemTypeExpression
                );

            Expression body = null;

            if (propType == typeof(string))
            {
                body = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Serializer<T>),
                    nameof(DoSomething),
                    Type.EmptyTypes,
                    Expression.Invoke(
                        getterExpression,
                        itemTypeExpression
                        ),
                    streamTypeExpression
                    );
            }
            else if (propType.IsArray)
            {
                var elementType = propType.GetElementType();
                var elementTypeExpression = Expression.Parameter(elementType);

                var serializerType = typeof(Serializer<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
                var serializerTypeExpression = Expression.Parameter(serializerType);

                body = Expression.Call(
                    serializerType,
                    nameof(DoSomethingElse),
                    Type.EmptyTypes,
                    Expression.Invoke(
                        getterExpression,
                        itemTypeExpression
                        ),
                    streamTypeExpression
                    );
            }
            if (body != null)
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Stream, int>>(body, itemTypeExpression, streamTypeExpression).Compile();
            return (T item, Stream stream) => 0;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please show sample input code along with your code working when it serializes a `Meow` (showing the output)? Then show as much code as you can for the serialization of a `Ruff` plus expected output etc?

Comment: And why are you using expressions to build this? Expressions are useful when you don't know the types at compile-time. Is that what you're expecting here? Is this meant to be a general-purpose serializer?

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah, a somewhat general-purpose serializer.  It'll serialize a few dozen Model classes according to special rules.  I could define a serializer for each one, but it'd be a pain and difficult to maintain.  As for input code:  Serializer<Meow>.GetSerializer()(new Meow(), null) <-- if a breakpoint DoSomething is hit, it works.  The same for Rawr instead of Meow is the challenge.

Comment: Please edit your question with the input code so that I can copy, paste, and run it. Then tell me what output you expect. Please take the time to do this so that I don't have to figure it out for myself. Then it means I can concentrate on giving you an answer rather than writing test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here, with the way you're constructing your expression, your `Ruff` type will not satisfy that expression.

You're effectively building up this expression:

```
(Rawr arg0, Stream arg1) =>
    Serializer<Ruff>.DoSomethingElse(arg0.Grr, arg1);
```

Note that the type of `arg0.Grr` is `Meow[]` but the expected type is `Ruff[]`. The `DoSomethingElse()` method must be generic instead to be compatible.

```
static int DoSomethingElse<TValue>(TValue[] values, Stream stream) => values.Length;
```

On the other hand,it doesn't seem to really matter what the actual underlying type is, you just want the length of the array. So instead, you could just make it an `Array` and it will still work.

```
static int DoSomethingElse(Array values, Stream stream) => values.Length;
```

Overall, I wouldn't mix up different types of expressions in that way (expression objects and lambdas), either build it all using lambdas or all using expressions. I'd write that method this way:

```
public static Func<T, Stream, int> GetSerializer()
{
    var firstProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().First();
    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var stream = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Stream));
    var propType = firstProperty.PropertyType;
    if (typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(propType))
    {
        var body = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Serializer<T>),
            "DoSomething",
            Type.EmptyTypes,
            Expression.Invoke(
                MakeGetter(firstProperty),
                item
            ),
            stream
        );
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Stream, int>>(body, item, stream).Compile();
    }
    if (typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(propType))
    {
        var body = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Serializer<T>),
            "DoSomethingElse",
            Type.EmptyTypes,
            Expression.Invoke(
                MakeGetter(firstProperty),
                item
            ),
            stream
        );
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Stream, int>>(body, item, stream).Compile();
    }
    return (T arg0, Stream arg1) => 0;

    Expression MakeGetter(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        var arg0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        return Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Property(arg0, prop),
            arg0
        );
    }
}
```

---

Based on your comments, it makes more sense to me to make the methods generic, rather than the serializer. You'll just need to make the appropriate expressions to the generic calls.

```
static class Serializer
{
    static int DoSomething(string value, Stream stream) => value.Length;
    static int DoSomethingElse<T>(T[] values, Stream stream) => values.Length;

    public static Func<T, Stream, int> GetSerializer<T>()
    {
        var firstProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().First();
        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var stream = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Stream));
        var propType = firstProperty.PropertyType;
        if (typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(propType))
        {
            var body = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Serializer),
                "DoSomething",
                Type.EmptyTypes,
                Expression.Invoke(
                    MakeGetter(firstProperty),
                    item
                ),
                stream
            );
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Stream, int>>(body, item, stream).Compile();
        }
        if (typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(propType))
        {
            var body = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Serializer),
                "DoSomethingElse",
                new[] { propType.GetElementType() },
                Expression.Invoke(
                    MakeGetter(firstProperty),
                    item
                ),
                stream
            );
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Stream, int>>(body, item, stream).Compile();
        }
        return (T arg0, Stream arg1) => 0;

        Expression MakeGetter(PropertyInfo prop)
        {
            var arg0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            return Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.Property(arg0, prop),
                arg0
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I'm not building up the expression Serializer<Ruff>.DoSomethingElse(…), but rather Serializer<Meow>.DoSomethingElse(…).  Essentially, the serializer for Ruff is discovering an array of type Meow as a property, and needs to call the Meow Serializer method to serialize all the Meow's in the array.  I do like your approach of Expression xor Lambda and will dig into them a bit more before more comment - thanks!

Comment: Oh, I get ya. So for every new type, you'd call the serializer version for that type. In that case, it would be more appropriate to make the methods generic, rather than the class. I'll update for that case.

Comment: No need to update - I figured it out thanks to your code.  You provided the missing pieces for me to wrap my head around how things work with Expressions.  I'll update my question to show the final solution I came up with thanks to you.